# Why is my modal partial view empty when I request ajax data in my MVC Application?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application I have a button that you can click on, the button triggers a bootstrap 4 modal which is a partial view.  Using Ajax is makes a call to a controller to return model data for the view to populate some of the textboxes.  Despite the ajax call working successfully when the modal pops up all the fields are empty.

Here is my code.  This is the function that runs when the button is clicked:

**editTab Function**

```
function editTab(id) {   
    if (id != undefined) {    
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Positions/_TabsEdit/" + id,
            success: function (responseData) {  
                console.log("Successfully GOT TabEdit data.");
                console.log(responseData)
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR.status);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    } else {
        //whatever    
    }
}
```

Here is my view with the partial view in place.

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
       <button id="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_editTabs">Triggers Bootstrap Modal</button>
    </div>
</div>
@Html.Partial("_TabsEdit")
```

**PartialView**

```
@model MyProject.Models.Tab    
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_editTabs" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">@ViewBag.Title</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Id)
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TabName)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
  public ActionResult _TabsEdit(int Id)
    {
        Tab tab = unitOfWork.TabRepository.GetByID(Id);
        return PartialView("_TabsEdit", tab);
    }
```

When I inspect my code I can see that the ajax call is successful and the data is returned but I don't know why my modal fields are empty.  I suspect I've set something up incorrectly, can anyone advise?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your action method and inspect the variable values are expected (id, tab etc). Debug.

Comment: You don't fill the data in the modal after the ajax call!

Comment: I'm not seeing where you are actually returning the data out of your ajax function. You are just console logging it. But, I don't know much about how this works.

Comment: No where in you code are you setting the value of anything in your modal - all you do is output the response using `console.log(responseData)` But you have not indicated what `responseData` is, or what values you want to update

Comment: It was my understanding that the data was returned by the controller i.e. `return PartialView("_TabEdit", tab)` The job of the ajax request was to pass the ID to the controller so it knows what to return to the partial view.